# .htaccess file won't work

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm running my app in XAMPP with CodeIgniter. I have a .htaccess file that will not necessitate me anymore of including index.php in url but it won't work.

The content of my .htaccess file is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|crossdomain\.xml|captcha|images|assets|archive|css|js|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I already set the all the directories with AllowOverride to All. I've already enabled mod_rewrite too but still my links won't work. Instead of going to the specified URL, it will go the XAMPP homepage.

Also in my config file, it looks like this:

> $config['base_url'] = '';
>   $config['index_page'] = '';

Then in view:

> a href="/signup"

Am I doing it right?  Please help.

Comment: Do you have codeigniter in some subdirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
# Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|monitor\.php|resources|test_gui|img|css|js|favicon\.ico|(.*)\.(png|js|jpg|swf|css|gif|ico|jpeg|scss)$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It still won't work. Am I right doing it right? In my config file: $config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';

also in view: <a href="/signup">Create an account</a>

Am I doing it right?